# Cannot resolve property

Tags: hibernate

I have prepared a sample application to understand the working of the

Hibernate Criteria Query Language.

I have prepared this using annotations.

All the fields have been specified, with their respective setter-getter methods.

Still, I am getting the following error :

```
could not resolve property: PRODUCT_PRICE of: com.anno.Product
```

The following, are my files :

Product.java

@Entity

@Table(name = "products", catalog = "myschema", uniqueConstraints = {

```
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "productId")})
```

public class Product {

```
private int productId;


private String proName;


private double price;



public Product(){}



public Product(int productId, String proName, Double price) {


    this.productId = productId;


    this.proName = proName;


    this.price = price;


}


@Id


@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)


@Column(name = "productId", unique = true, nullable = false)


public int getProductId() {


    return productId;


}


public void setProductId(int productId) {


    this.productId = productId;


}


public String getProName() {


    return proName;


}


public void setProName(String proName) {


    this.proName = proName;


}


@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)


@Column(name = "price", nullable = false)


public double getPrice() {


    return price;


}


public void setPrice(double price) {


    this.price = price;


}
```

}

#########################**MAIN CLASS**

```
    public class App { 


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")


        public static void main(String[] args)


        {


            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();


            cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml"); 


             SessionFactory sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory();  


             Session session=sf.openSession();  



            Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Product.class);


            Criterion cn = Restrictions.gt("PRODUCT_PRICE",new Double(17000));


            crit.add(cn);


            List<?> l=crit.list();


            System.out.println("List total size..._"+l.size());


            Iterator<?> it=l.iterator();





            while(it.hasNext())


            {

                Product p=(Product)it.next();


                System.out.println(p.getProductId());


                System.out.println(p.getProName());


                System.out.println(p.getPrice());


                System.out.println("-----------------");


            }



            session.close();


            sf.close();


        }

    }
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC


    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"


    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">



    <hibernate-configuration>


    <session-factory>


        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>


        <property
```

name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema

```
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>


        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin123</property>


        <property
```

name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

```
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>


        <mapping class="com.anno.Product" />




    </session-factory>


    </hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not work with column names in Hibernate, you work with the property names.

That means you have to Change:

```
Criterion cn = Restrictions.gt("PRODUCT_PRICE",new Double(17000));
```

to

```
Criterion cn = Restrictions.gt("price",new Double(17000));
```

Comment: I tried that, and now I am getting a new error : Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'this_.PRODUCT_ID' in 'field list'

Comment: can you Show the generated query?

Comment: select this_.PRODUCT_ID as PRODUCT_1_0_0_, this_.PRODUCT_PRICE as PRODUCT_2_0_0_, this_.proName as proName3_0_0_ from myschema.products this_ where this_.PRODUCT_PRICE>?

Comment: @Nishil and you are sure the column Name is correct?

Comment: This was a previously created table. It has existed before I built this application. Should I delete the table and re-run the program?

Comment: The field names in the table,created in workbench are : pid, pname, price

Comment: @Nishil You have to chnage the `@Column` Annotation, so that the column Name and the Name in `@Column` is identicaly

Comment: Another error :Unknown column 'this_.productId' in 'field list'

Comment: I have edited my question. My Product.java now looks like what is shown in the edited code

Comment: @Nishil Change `@Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)` to `@Column(name = "pid", unique = true, nullable = false)`

Comment: I did that,too. Now the error is  Unknown column 'this_.proName' in 'field list

Comment: @Nishil add the Annotation `@Column(name = "pname", nullable = false)` to `getProName`

Comment: did that,too. Now, is a completely new error Composite-id class must implement Serializable: com.anno.Product